# Mongo Preventing access to dangerous command

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Reading [Mongo: Definite guide](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mongodb-the-definitive/9781491954454/):

In first chapter, author mentions the following snippet to change some of the default commands of `db`:

```js
var no = function() {
   print("Not on my watch.");
};

// Prevent dropping databases
db.dropDatabase = DB.prototype.dropDatabase = no;

// Prevent dropping collections
DBCollection.prototype.drop = no;

// Prevent dropping an index
DBCollection.prototype.dropIndex = no;

// Prevent dropping indexes
DBCollection.prototype.dropIndexes = no;
```

I know `db` is pointing to current database, but my question is from where does `DB` is coming from?

Answer (score 3):

That is referring to the legacy [mongo shell](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/mongo/) which was deprecated in MongoDB v5.0 and has been replaced by [mongosh](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/). There is no `DB` in the `mongosh` shell.

If you are using an older version of MongoDB and have the `mongo` shell installed then `DB` is a global variable which resolves to a function with properties set by the Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) as part of the [`db.js`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/24908bdb95f97c75ee81478572e67daf2b409bc4/src/mongo/shell/db.js) execution.

The `DB.prototype.dropDatabase` is a function too so by running `db.dropDatabase = DB.prototype.dropDatabase = no;` you are referring to the [`dropDatabase`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/24908bdb95f97c75ee81478572e67daf2b409bc4/src/mongo/shell/db.js#L398) function which is now pointing to your `no` function.